# Parking Charges Calculation

Tags: c#, algorithm

THi so I'm struggling with a calculation for a parking system. I've been searching for someone who has a similar rate as me but have been unsuccessful.

so the calculation should be free for the first 30 minutes, 10 for the second 30 minutes and then 5 for every half hour after that.

e.g: 0, 10, 15, 20, 25, ect.

My idea was to subtract 60 minutes from the total minutes and then add 10 if the result is 0, and then if the result is > 0 add 5 for every next half hour after the first 60 minutes.

the problem with this is that when the amount of total minutes are 60< the minutes are 0 and then it is taken as free parking.

I feel like there should be an extra variable I could add for the first 2 half hours?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code snipit:

```
int rate = 5;

TimeSpan difference = timeOut - timeIn;

                double minutes = Math.Round(difference.TotalMinutes, 0);

                    double remainder = minutes % 30;

                    if (remainder != 0)
                    {
                        minutes = (minutes + (30 - remainder)) - 60;
                    }

                if (minutes < 30)
                {
                    minutes = 0;
                    TotalAmount = 0;
                    cashAmountText.Text = "0";
                    vatAmountText.Text = "0";
                    AmountDueText.Text = "0";
                    PayButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    FreeParking = "****Free Parking****";
                }
                else
                {
                    Amount_Due = ((minutes / 30) * rate) + 10;
                    TotalAmount = /*(Amount_Due  * 0.15) + */Amount_Due;
                    VatAmount = TotalAmount * 0.15;
                    Vat =/* TotalAmount - */VatAmount;
                    cashAmountText.Text = Amount_Due.ToString();
                    vatAmountText.Text = Math.Round(Vat, 0).ToString();
                    AmountDueText.Text = Math.Round(TotalAmount, 0).ToString();
                    PayButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    FreeParking = "****Thank You****";
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a complicated way to express "$5 per half hour, free if less than one half hour". We can just keep it simple, use the formula `halfHours * 5` to determine amount due, and simply zero out the `halfHours` if it's too small.

```cs
int rate = 5;
double halfHours = Math.Ceiling((timeOut - timeIn).totalMinutes / 30);

if (halfHours == 1) halfHours = 0;

Amount_Due = halfHours * rate;
TotalAmount = Amount_Due;
VatAmount = TotalAmount * 0.15;
cashAmountText.Text = Amount_Due.ToString();
vatAmountText.Text = Math.Round(VatAmount, 0).ToString();
AmountDueText.Text = Math.Round(TotalAmount, 0).ToString();
PayButton.IsEnabled = Amount_Due > 0;
FreeParking = Amount_Due > 0 ? "****Thank You****" : "****Free Parking****";
```

I left your further calculations untouched, but I do wonder why `AmountDueText` should contain `TotalAmount` and why `TotalAmount` always equals `Amount_Due`. Shouldn't `TotalAmount` include tax added?

Comment: @RufusL I just mimicked the asker's code: `if (minutes < 30)` - charges begin to accrue the instant 30 minutes have passed.

Comment: Hi @Klaycon, What you stated is correct.  the Total amount should technically include the vat amount but the client insisted that the $10 for the second half hour covers the vat. I have tried to convince y client that the total should have the vat included. but alas I can't force it on them xD.

I also observed that your solution excludes the second half hour to be 10? or do you think this could also work?

```if(halfhours < 2) halfhours = 0;

Amount_Due = (halfhours *rate) + 10```

Comment: @MadelineKallis When `halfHours` is `2`, `Amount_Due` will be set to `2 * rate` which is 10. So it is $10 for the second half hour as you require. Your proposed code seems to be complicating things again - it will be wrong for `halfHours = 3` (returns $25).

Comment: @MadelineKallis The only thing that may be different from your requirements is that at 31 minutes, the amount will be just above $5 instead of just above $0. I'm not sure which way your client wants, or if they want only to charge in even $5 increments and not partial amounts, but the modifications either way are simple.

Comment: Yeah they don't want any cents so 31 minutes would be 5. and thank you for your responses. It helps a lot. and I do tend to over complicate things. This really simplifies my thinking process.

Comment: rate is also set as a value in the database which can be changed by the client. It Gives my project more flexibility to adapt to other potential clients who would be interested in my system.

Comment: @MadelineKallis It sounds like you should round down the amount of half-hours, so that e.g. 1.99 results in 1, which will be set to 0. I will edit my answer in kind.

Comment: if i were to have 17 minutes as a remainder how would I handle that? Would it count the remainder as another half hour?

Comment: if result were to be 1.99 it means that 59 minutes (around) would have passed so it would have to charge $10

Comment: @MadelineKallis Can you specify the expected behavior here? Should 47 minutes charge $10 or $0? What about 45 minutes even?

Comment: ```minutes > 30  = 0```, ```60 > minutes > 30 = $10```, ```infinity > minutes > 60 += $5```. So it would be 0,10,15,20,25, ect

Comment: You said "31 minutes would be 5" earlier, did you mean 10? It seems `Math.Ceiling` would be better then. Will edit answer.

Comment: that was a mistake I just ment that even it it would be 1 minute or a few into the next half hour it would add the next rate

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Klaycon.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set a temp variable to track how many minutes are left, and then subtract from it while you add to the result for each 30 minute span:

```
var timeIn = DateTime.Now;

// Hard code this for testing (3 hours and 30 minutes
var timeOut = timeIn.AddHours(3).AddMinutes(30);

TimeSpan difference = timeOut - timeIn;

double minutes = Math.Round(difference.TotalMinutes, 0);
double minutesRemaining = minutes;
int result = 0; // Charge for the first 30 minutes

if (minutesRemaining > 30)
{
    result += 10; // Charge for the second 30 minutes
    minutesRemaining -= 60;
}

while (minutesRemaining > 0)
{
    result += 5;
    minutesRemaining -= 30;
}
```